# Error rederizing PDF with formulas on iOS 15 with Swift 4 using PDFKit PDFDocument

Tags: ios, swift

When generating a new PDF for each page using PDFDocument, like this:

```
urlSession.dataTask(with: pagesRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let dataList = data {
                if let document = PDFDocument(data: Data(base64Encoded: dataList.base64EncodedString())!) {
                    var count = 1
                    while count <= document.pageCount {
                        if (document.page(at: (count - 1)) != nil) {
                            
                            let page = document.page(at: count - 1)
                            
                            let pdfData = Data(base64Encoded: pagePdfBase64!),
                            let fileName = "\(self.folderName)/\(String(count)).pdf")
                            
                            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.documentsPath).appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
                            
                            do {
                                try pdfData.write(to: url.absoluteURL)
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

On iOS 14 the pdf is generated without problems.

[image: ios 14 rendering]

The same code when generating using iOS 15 the same pdf does not show the values:

[image: ios 15 rendering]

Comment: Are you drawing the content of the PDF yourself?  What does the code look like where you actually draw the text?

Comment: I'm not drawing the PDF content, this comes from a rest service, so I don't have direct access to the PDF, but I can do a browser test and I can see the encoded content PDF content

Comment: OK.  I do know that Apple released a reworking of their text engine in iOS 15 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10061/) so I thought that might be a cause, but if you're not drawng the text yourself, that seems less likely.

Comment: @ScottThompson I found out that the problem is in the pdf font, there is some font in the pdf that is causing the problem at render time, the font doesn't seem to exist on iOS, when I run the tests better I get the following error "Replacing TrueType font 'Arial, Bold' with 'Arial-BoldMT'"